# DRY ruby on rails loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to loop through my users and sum an attribute `act_points` from associated `post_activites` and then assign and save it to my users table attribute `total_points`. The code below works for me but it doesn't follow DRY.

```
<% @users.order("total_points desc").each do |u| %> 
  <p><% u.total_points = u.post_activities.sum(:act_points).round(2) %> </p>
  <% u.total_points %>
  <% u.save %>
<%end%>
<% @users.order("total_points desc").each do |u| %> 
  <p><% u.total_points = u.post_activities.sum(:act_points).round(2) %> </p>
  <%= u.total_points %>
<%end%>
```

Any suggestions on how to combine these loops or shorten them?

Comment: My first reaction after reading the code - why are you calling save within a view?! This is a huge NO-NO.

Comment: I know it's not in production and again I'm super new to this and it was the only thing I could think of forgive me ... Lol

Answer (score 3):

You can refactore your code in this way:

```
# user.rb
def actual_points
  post_activities.sum(:act_points).round(2)
end

def update_total_points
  update(total_points: actual_points)
end

# in controller (change index to your method)
def index
  @users = User.order("total_points desc")
  @users.find_each do |user|
    user.update_total_points
  end
end

# view
<% @users.each do |u| %> 
  <%= u.total_points %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: thank you, you have no idea how much this helped me learn about this question and so many  more problems i was having thanks